# Display /dev/videoX feed in a GUI on Linux-ARM64

Tags: ubuntu, .net-core, arm, video-capture, avaloniaui

I've got a device running Ubuntu 18.04LTS on a 64-bit ARM processor. I'd like to develop a GUI that will let me access the camera feed of potentially multiple attached devices (/dev/video0, /dev/video1). Ideally this will be possible with a .NET stack (.NET Core and AvaloniaUI are what I'm looking at). I'm aware of using P/Invoke, but only have a rough understanding of using it. I'm also aware of the [libv4l2](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.8/media/uapi/v4l/libv4l-introduction.html) library, however I'm not sure where to go from there.

If I have to phrase this as a more direct question for SO: *How can I display the /dev/videoX feed on an Ubuntu-ARM64 device in a GUI app built with NET Core (ideally with AvaloniaUI)?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install https://www.nuget.org/packages/LibVLCSharp.Avalonia/
2. MainWindow.axaml

```xml
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:vlc="clr-namespace:LibVLCSharp.Avalonia;assembly=LibVLCSharp.Avalonia"
        mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
        x:Class="AvaloniaCam.MainWindow"
        Title="AvaloniaCam">
        <vlc:VideoView x:Name="VideoView"/>
</Window>
```

3. MainWindow.axaml.cs:

```cs
    public class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            AvaloniaXamlLoader.Load(this);
            if(Design.IsDesignMode)
                return;
            var videoView = this.Get<VideoView>("VideoView");
            var libVlc = new LibVLC();
            videoView.MediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(libVlc);
            videoView.MediaPlayer.Play(new Media(libVlc, "v4l2://", FromType.FromLocation));
        }
    }
```

Note that you might need `libvlc-dev` package installed for P/Invoke layer from libvlcsharp to work.

Comment: It's working as intended now, thanks again @kekekeks !

I removed the XAML Style line and moved the logic to the ViewModel instead of the CB. 

One last question if you get a chance and see this: How do I specify which feed to pull the video from? I've got multiple cameras setup on this device. Would it be something simple like changing the "mrl path" to `"v4l2://dev/video3"` and creating multiple VideoView, LibVLC, and Media objects?

Comment: Yes, you can specify the device node in the url and you can use multiple player objects. Also see https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Modules/v4l2/

Comment: Going to mark this as an answer because you answered the question that I was asking for, however future readers should be cautious and check both  https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/issues/5796 and https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp/-/issues/458 to see if the bug relating to multiple VideoView controls is fixed before spending time trying to implement it. For single camera systems, I believe this implementation might work as it stands for you.

Comment: That's probably an issue in LibVLCSharp integration library, since I haven't got any sizing issues when I was playing around with mplayer: https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/e2f618dcb9ac0178a491cf9fcd0fddb6c0878924/samples/interop/NativeEmbedSample/EmbedSample.cs#L30-L39 You can grab the video feed using `mplayer -vo x11 tv:// -tv driver=v4l2:device=/dev/video0 -zoom  -wid <handle>`

Comment: Mkay, reproduced with mplayer. Seems to be an Avalonia bug

Comment: Fixed in 0.10.2